# CSS3 Menu how to change background color

Tags: css

i want to add a background color ON Mouser Over for a CSS3 menu, i've found something on stackoverflow but it's not working for me....i think i got to change something in the .menu a{ } but i don't know what....can someone help me?

Thanks

```
    #menu, #menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

body{margin: 0 auto;}
    .menu100percent {
background: #cce2ff; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #cce2ff 1%, #75bdd1 26%, #002a6d 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(1%,#cce2ff), color-stop(26%,#75bdd1), color-stop(100%,#002a6d)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #cce2ff 1%,#75bdd1 26%,#002a6d 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #cce2ff 1%,#75bdd1 26%,#002a6d 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #cce2ff 1%,#75bdd1 26%,#002a6d 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #cce2ff 1%,#75bdd1 26%,#002a6d 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#cce2ff', endColorstr='#002a6d',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */


    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 30px;
    width:100%;
}
 .menu{width:1000px; margin: 0 auto; }
 .menu a{color:#fff; font-size:12px; line-height:370px; font-family:Arial; text-decoration:none; text-align: left;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `:hover` selector:

```
.menu:hover a {
    background-color: gold;
}
```

Comment: I tried it...somethings wrong...i want for each item of the menu....in this case all of the menus are becoming gold....Look Here http://jsfiddle.net/snP3Z/

Comment: Ok, try this instead: `li:hover > a { background-color: gold; }`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the css code:

```
.menu a : hover {
    background-color: gold;
}
```

Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/snP3Z/3/